# std::map::clear and elements' destructors

Tags: c++, stdstring, stdmap

Does destructor get called on `std::map` elements when `std::map::clear` is used?

I tried to debug for `std::map<string,string>` but could not see `std::string` destructor getting invoked. Can any one please help my understanding?

Documentation states it gets called, but I could not notice it.

Comment: How do you "notice" `std::string` destructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Documentation is right, it does get called.

The destruction will be done by the method `std::allocator<T>::deallocate()`. Trace through that in your debugger.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/allocator/

Comment: Some how I missed it, but I could see my break point being hit at std::string destructor, and yes indeed the call stack came from std::allocator.

Thanks for your time John.

Answer (score 5):

The destructor does get called. Here is an example to illustrate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class A
{
 public:
  A() { std::cout << "Constructor " << this << std::endl; }
  A(const A& other) { std::cout << "Copy Constructor " << this << std::endl; }
  ~A() { std::cout << "Destructor " << this <<std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
  std::map<std::string, A> mp;

  A a;

  mp.insert(std::pair<std::string, A>("hello", a));
  mp.clear();

  std::cout << "Ending" << std::endl;
}
```

This will report an output similar to this:

```
Constructor 0xbf8ba47a
Copy Constructor 0xbf8ba484
Copy Constructor 0xbf8ba48c
Copy Constructor 0x950f034
Destructor 0xbf8ba48c
Destructor 0xbf8ba484
Destructor 0x950f034
Ending
Destructor 0xbf8ba47a
```

So, you can see that the destructors get called by the calling the clear function.

Comment: Yes I agree with your code, but I was aiming at std::string objects rather than user defined objects. Thanks for your time Chris.

Answer (score 0):

try with a `std::map<A,B>` where `A` and `B` are custom types that have a destructor in which you have set a breakpoint. You will see that it does get invoked, and exactly what scope this destruction happens at.

Comment: True, but i was looking for std::string though, my question got answered by the below comment, the reference link served the purpose to re-check my understanding, as it improved assurance level in my thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit more of a complete test, building on Chris Mansley's code as I wanted to see the effect on values, ptrs and refs - and I wanted to see the difference 
between clear and erase. No difference. In summary the destructor is only called
for value types, which you would expect. I just like to check my understanding 8)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class A
{
public:
    std::string some_data;

    A(std::string some_data) : some_data(some_data) {
        std::cout << "  A(" << some_data << ") @" << this << std::endl;
    }
    A(const A& other) {
        some_data = other.some_data;
        std::cout << "  Copy A(" << other.some_data << ") @" << this << std::endl;
    }
    ~A() {
        std::cout << "  Destruct ~A(" << some_data << ") @" << this << std::endl;
    }
};

void clear_test_value (void)
{
    std::cout << "clear_test_value() {" << std::endl;
    std::map<std::string, A> mp;
    A a("A1 data");
    mp.insert(std::pair<std::string, A>("key1", a));
    mp.clear();
    std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void erase_test_value (void)
{
    std::cout << "erase_test_value() {" << std::endl;
    std::map<std::string, A> mp;
    A a("A1 data");
    mp.insert(std::pair<std::string, A>("key2", a));
    auto f = mp.find("key2");
    if (f == mp.end()) {
        std::cout << "failed to find element {" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    mp.erase(f);
    std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void clear_test_ptr (void)
{
    std::cout << "clear_test_ptr() {" << std::endl;
    std::map<std::string, A*> mp;
    A a("A1 data");
    mp.insert(std::pair<std::string, A*>("key1", &a));
    mp.clear();
    std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void erase_test_ptr (void)
{
    std::cout << "erase_test() {" << std::endl;
    std::map<std::string, A*> mp;
    A a("A1 data");
    mp.insert(std::pair<std::string, A*>("key2", &a));
    auto f = mp.find("key2");
    if (f == mp.end()) {
        std::cout << "failed to find element {" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    mp.erase(f);
    std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void clear_test_ref (void)
{
    std::cout << "clear_test_ref() {" << std::endl;
    std::map<std::string, A&> mp;
    A a("A1 data");
    mp.insert(std::pair<std::string, A&>("key1", a));
    mp.clear();
    std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void erase_test_ref (void)
{
    std::cout << "erase_test_ref() {" << std::endl;
    std::map<std::string, A&> mp;
    A a("A1 data");
    mp.insert(std::pair<std::string, A&>("key2", a));
    auto f = mp.find("key2");
    if (f == mp.end()) {
        std::cout << "failed to find element {" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    mp.erase(f);
    std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
    clear_test_value();
    erase_test_value();
    clear_test_ptr();
    erase_test_ptr();
    clear_test_ref();
    erase_test_ref();

    return (0);
}
```

Output:

```
clear_test_value() {
  A(A1 data) @0x7ffee07389a0
  Copy A(A1 data) @0x7ffee0738960
  Copy A(A1 data) @0x7fe98fc029c8
  Destruct ~A(A1 data) @0x7ffee0738960
  Destruct ~A(A1 data) @0x7fe98fc029c8
}

  Destruct ~A(A1 data) @0x7ffee07389a0
erase_test_value() {
  A(A1 data) @0x7ffee07387f0
  Copy A(A1 data) @0x7ffee07387b0
  Copy A(A1 data) @0x7fe98fc029c8
  Destruct ~A(A1 data) @0x7ffee07387b0
  Destruct ~A(A1 data) @0x7fe98fc029c8
}

  Destruct ~A(A1 data) @0x7ffee07387f0
clear_test_ptr() {
  A(A1 data) @0x7ffee07389b0
}

  Destruct ~A(A1 data) @0x7ffee07389b0
erase_test() {
  A(A1 data) @0x7ffee0738800
}

  Destruct ~A(A1 data) @0x7ffee0738800
clear_test_ref() {
  A(A1 data) @0x7ffee07389b0
}

  Destruct ~A(A1 data) @0x7ffee07389b0
erase_test_ref() {
  A(A1 data) @0x7ffee0738800
}

  Destruct ~A(A1 data) @0x7ffee0738800
```